# jQueryUI Accordion effect selected tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using the jQueryUI Accordion effect in a webpage. However, I ditched the pre-packaged CSS sheet in favor of my own. The only problem is, I don't know how to make my tabs stay a certain color (they have a hover color-fill effect) when they are selected. Can anyone help? Below is a picture so you can see what I mean (I have my mouse over the green tab, but I want it to stay like that when selected) Thanks!

[website http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/3109/website.jpg](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/3109/website.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe theme roller css controls that with the class `ui-state-active`

```
 .ui-state-active { background-color: green; }
```

It works by:  jQuery will automatically add that class at runtime to the tab that is clicked.  Setting this in CSS ahead of time will then style the selected tab with that class's style.